# Extracting ISO files in 7z.dll- Out of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, iso, 7zip, sevenzipsharp

I have used two wrappers now to try to extract an ISO file. But no success

I have tried [sevenzipsharp](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) and [C-NET-Interface-for-7-Zip-Archive-DLLs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27148/C-NET-Interface-for-7-Zip-Archive-DLLs) But they both give this same Exception.
The ISO file contains .vob files(movies) and the total size of the ISO file is 4.35GB. When I try to extract a single .vob file of 1GB from it, I get Out of Memory Exception.

I actually want to extract the .vob files and then stream them over Upnp/DLNA

```
    SevenZipExtractor Extractor;
    try
      {
         String[] FileNames = RawFileExtractor(path, out Extractor);
         Extractor.ExtractFile(FileNames[8], ms) //the 1GB file: exception is here
      }
    catch{}
    Extractor.Dispose();
```

Comment: Are you using the 64-bit native libraries from 7-zip? Can you extract the ISO file using the 7-zip command line, GUI or shell extension?

Comment: I'm using 32 bit and my app is 32 bit version. Actually the code works if I try to extract a smaller .vob file from the ISo file.

Comment: If the entire file is kept in-memory at some point, you can't handle files of that size within 32 bits.

Comment: So, how much memory does it use and how much do you have? Extracting a 1GB file to memory will make at least one copy... 2GB gone just for that one file.

Comment: My Ram is  8GB and my C Drive has 4GB remaining. 
Is there a better way to do this ISO extraction and streaming in c#? I am now afraid that even if I meet the conditions, users of my program may not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     Extractor.ExtractFile(FileNames[8], ms)
```

Can't see "ms" but it is guessable at a MemoryStream.  That indeed is not going to work so well with a jiggabyte file.  *Very* likely to get an OutOfMemoryException when your program runs as a 32-bit process.  Easy enough to fix on your machine, you've to the horsepower.  Project + Properties, Build tab, select AnyCPU and untick "Prefer 32-bit" if you see it.

Still *very* wasteful and not exactly guaranteed to work on your user's machine if he doesn't have a 64-bit operating system.  Pretty unclear what you are actually doing with that MemoryStream, high odds that you should use a FileStream instead so it is directly extracted to the disk.  You'll use 4096 bytes instead of a jiggabyte.  A video player doesn't care if it plays from memory or the disk.  Also review the wisdom of compressing video, it is already compressed by the encoder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, My main problem is not still solved but atleast the out of memory problem was caused by loading the stream in memory. Now I tried to sned the stream directly to the client socket stream as shown here  Extractor.ExtractFile(FileNames[8], request.Socket.GetStream()); I still get socket Exception but a huge part of the stream is received by the Client. Is there any suggestion of how I can accomplish this safely. 1) I need to open the ISO file using 7zip(takes a file path as input) and stream as output. 2) then stream this oput put to the client socket.